# Amplify "npm install --save aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-angular" breaks the code

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services

Following this tutorial:

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/angular/#install-amplify-libraries

when I do `npm install --save aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-angular` I get compilation error

```
Error: node_modules/type-fest/ts41/get.d.ts:93:37 - error TS2344: Type 'BaseType' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string | number, any>'
```

I follow the advice in https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/10775 and now it compiles but shows empty screen

Comment: What exactly the requirement here is ? Do you want to install Amplify ? If Yes then npm i aws-amplify .. if you want to specify a specific version . Specify the version as 
" npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli@5.4.0" 
For Ui - angular i guess this is the npm command
"npm i @aws-amplify/ui-angular@2.4.27"

Answer (score 0):

I was using node 16.15 - upgrade to 16.17 solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your package.json file

```
  "overrides": {
    "type-fest": "3.3.0"
  }
```

The issue is with type-fest, @aws-sdk/middleware-retry has a has transitive dependency. This has been fixed in [aws/aws-sdk-js-v3#2191](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/pull/2191) - more info to the above issue [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/10775)